# git add node modules no response

Tags: git, github, npm, node-modules, github-pages

As mentioned in the title, I can't add my node_modules file to my repo. I added all the other files. Then I did git commit -m "Initial Commit". Finally, I did git push origin master and was able to push all the other changes for my other files. However when I do git add node_modules, it does not work. I don't get any response. Just a blank line with cursor. I don't have a .gitignore file as other posts may suggest. I can't figure it out. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So first you should exclude the `node_modules` folder from your git and use a proper deployment where you run the npm commands on your server. That folder will be very big. Or run  your script for combining your script and then add only that files to your repo.

When you try to add a folder to git you have to do it recursivly. So you can to the following.

```
git add --all
```

or

```
git add -A node_modules/
```

The option `-A` adds new files and delete files that are marked for deletion.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using node modules only for sass.

Comment: Also, I did git add -A node_modules/ and I received several lines saying "create mode 100644 node_modules/..." Then I tried to do git push origin master, but my push was rejected.